# Cannot access wsdl file from different machine

Tags: wsdl

I am trying to run the running Client & Server Application on different machine but then I am getting below exception message which says it can not get wsdl file on that machine:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at:
>   http://localhost:8080/proj_name/EmpServices?wsdl. It failed with: Got
>   http://localhost:8080/proj_name/EmpServices?wsdl while opening stream
>   from same_link_as_above/EmpServices?wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like connection issue, not WSDL or service-related.

### Possible causes and solutions:

1. You tell about "remote machine", but errors says "localhost".
   Have you configured your service client to work with your remote machine?
   Shouldn't it be remote machine's address? Or is it just a typo?
2. If you configured it correctly, make sure that you have a working connection and port 8080 is allowed in your firewalls.
   You may also try to open this link directly in your browser from client machine, and see what is says.
   Perhaps, you will get connection error message, while you should get WSDL file.